# euclidean division gets wrong result in c

Tags: c

I'am trying to write a programm that returns the minimum number of coins needed for change the problem seems to be in the dimes loop for example this is the result when i enter 12.29:

value: 1229
you need 49 qaurter(s)
you need -1091950400 dime(s)
you need 0 nickle(s)
you need 4 penny(s)
Coins needed are:-1091950347

```
int remain, quotient, dime, penny, quarter, nickle, value=round 
(get_positive_value()*100);
printf("value: %d\n", value);
 while (value>25)
{
    remain= value%25;
    quarter= value/25;
    value=remain;
}
printf("you need %d qaurter(s)\n",quarter);
while (value>10)
{
    dime= value/10;
    remain= value%10;
    value=remain;

}
printf("you need %d dime(s)\n",dime);
while (value>5)
{
     nickle= value/5;
     remain= value%5;
     value= remain;
}
printf("you need %d nickle(s)\n",nickle);
while (value>1)
{
    penny= value/1;
    value=0;
}
printf("you need %d penny(s)\n",penny);
printf("Coins needed are:%d\n",penny+quarter+nickle+dime);
```

}

Comment: You need to initialize the variables.

Comment: Consider if `value` was less than 25 from the onset. Then `quarter` would not be initialized, and your print statement would read from uninitialized memory to print its value. The same logic for your other coins.

Comment: You tell `scanf` to parse an integer which is a good decision for currencies. On the other side, entering `12.29` does not make much sense. From your sample it seems you enter `1229` correctly. Your text should match the code & sample.

Comment: Also, those `while` loops can be changed to `if` statements because the condition being tested will be false after the first iteration.

Comment: Also, those `>` tests should be `>=`.

Comment: It is not necessary either to initialize the variables  or to change the `while` statements into `if` statements. We can simply delete the `while` parts, leaving the bodies.

Comment: Thank you ian you were so helpful it's solved now